# parsing Unix timestamp to date string in the client side

Tags: c#, javascript

```
res.SentTime.substring(6,19)
```

"1318319100000"

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(res.SentTime.substring(6,19));
```

1318319100000

why doesn't it parses to date string?

Answer (score 3):

Multiply the timestamps by `1000`. You'll get mili seconds. Pass it to the `Date` constructor in JS.

In your code do this,

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(res.SentTime.substring(6,19),10)*1000);
```